# To find factor of a polynomial equation

Tags: linear-algebra

> One of the factors of $4x^2+y^2+14x-7y-4xy+12$ is equal to
>
> 1. $2x-y+4$
> 2. $2x-y-3$
> 3. $2x+y-4$
> 4. $2x-y+3$

Step $1$:
$4x^2+y^2-4xy$ can be simplified as $(2x-y)^2$

Step $2$:
$14x-7y$ can be simplified as $7(2x-y)$

and finally

$(2x-y) (2x-y+7) + 12$

I can able to factor to this extent only. however can't able to arrive at the answer.

The answer is given in the book. it states that $4x^2+y^2+14x-7y-4xy+12$ is product of $(2x-y+3)$ and $(2x-y+4)$ I am in need of steps

Comment: have you made a typo?

Comment: Did you mean mistake? I dont think so.

Comment: $(2x-y)^2+7(2x-y)$ is written as $(2x-y)(2x-y+7)$

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do $2x-y=k$ and then

$$k^2+7k+12=(k+3)(k+4)$$

and then you get

$$(2x-y+3)(2x-y+4)$$

Answer (score 4):

We can write the given equation as the product of two smaller polynomials:
\begin{align}
  \rlap{4x^2+y^2+14x−7y−4xy+12} \\
  &= (ax+by+c)(dx+ey+f) \\
  &= adx^2+aexy+afx+bdxy+bey^2+bfy+cdx+cey+cf \\
  &= \rlap{adx^2+bey^2+(af+cd)x+(bf+ce)y+(ae+bd)xy+cf}
\end{align}

We can equate coefficients to get the following:

\begin{align}4 &= ad \tag{$x^2$ term} \\
1  &= be \tag{$y^2$ term} \\
14 &= af+cd \tag{$x$ term} \\
-7 &= bf+ce \tag{$y$ term} \\
-4 &= ae+bd \tag{$xy$ term} \\
12 &= cf \tag{constant term}\end{align}

We can solve these simultaneous equations to get 
\begin{align}a &= 2  \\
b &= -1 \\
c &= 4  \\
d &= 2  \\
e &= -1 \\
f &= 3\end{align}

Therefore, we can say that $$4 x^2 + y^2 + 14 x − 7 y − 4 x y + 12 = (2 x - y + 4) (2 x - y + 3)$$